# Call to undefined function permissions()

Tags: php, laravel-5, relationship

i have create user roles and permissions using Laravel 5.8. i created users and roles correctly, but when i am creating many to many model relationship between permissions and roles, an error occurred and said "Call to undefined function permissions()". i have created a getPermissions() method to retrieve all permissions according to role id. But also laravel said that method need to be static. i do not know what is the reason. why the permissions() relationship method not working?

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Role extends Model
{
   public function users()
   {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\AdminUser', 'role_user', 'role_id', 'user_id');
   }

public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Permission', 'permission_role', 'role_id', 
    'permission_id');
}

public static function getPermissions()
{   
      if(Auth::guard('adminuser')->check()){

          $permissions = "Dashboard, Appointments, Customer Records"; 
          $admin_user_id = Auth::guard('adminuser')->user()->id;

          $role_id = 1;//roles()->select('id')->where('roles.id', $admin_user_id)->first();
          $per = permissions()->select($permissions)->where('permissions.id', $role_id)->first();

          return $per;
      }
}
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The error is in your `getPermissions()` method, `permissions()` does not exist, should be `$this->permissions()`. And probably not static

Comment: @kerbholz thanks. i add $this but this error occurred "Non-static method App\Models\Role::getPermissions() should not be called statically". how can i solve this?

Comment: Did you make it non-static? Instead of `Role::getPermissions()` (static) use something like `$role->getPermissions()` (non-static)

Comment: @kerbholz yes. i made that non-static and change to this`$per = $this->permissions()....`

Comment: @kerbholz i changed it but in my blade view i added this `{{App\Models\Role::getPermissions()->permissions }}` but this error occurred "Non-static method App\Models\Role::getPermissions() should not be called statically". how can i access that model method in blade view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`permissions()` is an instance method, not a class method.
Therefore, you must call it on an instance of that class.

Inside `getPermissions()` method, change:

```php
$per = permissions()->select($permissions)->where('permissions.id', $role_id)->first();
```

into

```php
$per = $this->permissions()->select($permissions)->where('permissions.id', $role_id)->first();
```

`permissions()` couldn't be static, since it is calling another instance method (`$this->belongsToMany()`)

#### Edit

My bad, didn't saw that `getPermissions` was static.

You have to remove the `static` keyword from `getPermissions()`. Anyway, there is a lot of mixing going on there. You are using static methods to access instance methods, and this is wrong.

Comment: thanks. i changed it but in my blade view i added this `{{App\Models\Role::getPermissions()->permissions }}` but this error occurred "Non-static method App\Models\Role::getPermissions() should not be called statically". how can i access that model method in blade view?

Comment: `{{App\Models\Role::getPermissions()` will never work. You are trying to call an instance method in a static way. You **must** have an instance of that class, and call `getPermissions()` on **that** object!

Comment: thanks a lot. can you please tell me how to do that. i'm new to laravel.

Comment: i created a instance.`$role_id = 1;
              $per = $this->permissions()->select('permissions')->where('permissions.id', $role_id)->first();
              dd($per);` this returns null, what is the problem?